# Chart for deciphering terms in different programming languages

Tags: php, python, programming-languages

This has been bugging me every since I started to use Python - in PHP you have this ability to use a string as a key in an array. PHP calls these associative arrays. Python calls these dictionaries.

Does anyone know of a premade chart that will let me see what the different terminology is in different languages. For example:

PHP             | Python
Associative array | Dictionary

Comment: Do Not Do This.  The terms are not trivial mappings.  If they were, there would be trivial translators among languages.  It's not that simple, and trying to simplify will lead to more confusion.

Comment: *(related)* http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-pythonbasics/index.html?ca=dgr-twtrPython4PHPdth-OS

Comment: @S.Lott: I agree with everything but your first sentence. There's nothing wrong with helpful analogies to kick start a process.

Comment: +1@S.Lott: a python dictionary is nothing like a PHP array, and they are both different from Java LolMaps

Comment: Perl calls them "hashes", which is confusing since other applications consider hashes to be the results of hash functions, e.g. MD5 or SHA1.  This chart will look like the Worst Powerpoint Ever before you're 10% done.

Comment: The terms "Associative array, dictionary, hash, table, hash table" cover most languages.  You will learn more if you match them up yourself :-)

Comment: @webbiedave: They aren't "helpful" analogies.  They're misleading analogies, and it's shortsighted to keep referring back to PHP while "learning" Python.  You can't go to the well with a full bucket.  Languages are *different*.  It's deeper than different syntax.  In some cases, it's fundamentally different concepts.

Comment: @Lott: Hmm, I don't know Python so maybe if you're talking about this specific feature your comment is valid. But in general to say that when learning a new language you should throw away everything you already know and start over ... why? I found it quite helpful when learning Java to read things like "A Java class is a lot like a C++ class except that ..."

Comment: @Jay: Absolutely. It can be a helpful jumping off point for grasping concepts more quickly.

Comment: Perhaps I should have left PHP out of the picture because there seems to be some biased opinions on PHP. It was the best example I could think of when I wrote the question. But, the fact still stands a dictionary in Python is an associative array in PHP. Which, it makes it hard to read documentation...if a programmer doesn't even know what a dictionary is supposed to mean. I feel that if such a chart existed, one can go "oh, X is similar to Y in the Z language I know how to use those", than "wth is J?...Google time!".This question is just limited to Python or PHP, I want to include C#/Java ect

Comment: @Lo'oris Please explain, because the Python documentation says "Dictionaries are sometimes found in other languages as “associative memories” or “associative arrays”." http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html So, please, explain your comment of "a python dictionary is nothing like a PHP array". Unless you are talking about an array indexed by numerical values, which, I am clearly not talking about in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where to find a chart, but Wikipedia has a detailed [article about associative arrays in various languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28mapping%29)

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below URL will solve your issue...this is ant a chat but see this blog, which express the performance management.

http://www.insideria.com/2008/04/dictionaries-and-associative-a.html

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a handy cheatsheet for your reference,

for python checkout http://www.addedbytes.com/download/python-cheat-sheet-v1/png/

for PHP checkout http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/php-cheat-sheet/